# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Created route `handler` and while adding in my `route`.

```
import {Application, NextFunction} from 'express';
import {container} from 'tsyringe';
const routeConstantsArray  = { };

const constants: any  = []
constants.push(routeConstantsArray)
let next : NextFunction;
export const loadConstantsMiddleware = (app:Application) => {
    app.locals = constants
    next();
};
```

**Route**

```
import express from 'express';
import {Application} from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
// Import Internal Modules
import {loadConstantsMiddleware} from '../core/middleware/constants_middleware';
 const startupRouterConfig = (app: Application): Application => {
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(loadConstantsMiddleware(app));
    return app;
};
```

**Error**
 (parameter) app: `express.Application`
    No overload matches this call.
      The last overload gave the following error:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(55, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the `loadConstantsMiddleware` as middleware, you have to return a request handler, like:

```js
export const loadConstantsMiddleware = (app:Application) => {
    app.locals = constants;
    return (req, res, next) => {
      next();
    }
};
```

But in this scenario, it probably doesn't make sense to use it as a middleware since the constants are scoped to the entire application (versus just the request).

To just add it to the app directly, without middleware, you can do:

```js
// main
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
loadConstantsMiddleware(app);

// load-constants-middleware
export const loadConstantsMiddleware = (app:Application) => {
  app.locals = constants
};
```