# 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams', when adding the retrieveUserId in server.ts

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I get this error:

[image: This is the error]

**Server.ts**

```
    import * as express from 'express';
    import {Application} from "express";
    import * as fs from 'fs';
    import * as https from 'https';
    import {retrieveUserId} from './user-middleware-extraction';

    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');



const app: Application = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(retrieveUserId);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

`
**User-middleware-extraction.ts**

```
import { NextFunction,Request,Response } from "express";
import { decodeToken } from "./security.utils";

export function retrieveUserId(res:Response,req:Request,next:NextFunction) {
    const jwt = req.cookies['SESSIONID']   // retrieving the jwtoken
    if(jwt) {
        handleSession(jwt, req)
      .then(()=>
      next())
      .catch(err=>
        {
            console.log(err);
            next()    
        })
    }
}

async function  handleSession(jwt, req) {
    try {
        req['userId'] = payload.sub//request contain the id
        var payload = await decodeToken(jwt)//payload of the jwt
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log("error is", err)
    }
}
```

While assigning the middleware to server.ts this error is popping up. No idea what is causing this to happen.

Is the issue with the middleware functionality?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836853/argument-of-type-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-pathparams ?

Comment: No the middleware streucture is different here.

Comment: Well, yes. But you are also not returning anything from your middleware. So I assume the problem is the same.

Comment: Where do we add the return bro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. It seems like you just have to exchange req and res function parameters in order to get matching types.

Order of path params should be: `(req, res, next)`. You switched up request and response params.

Comment: Also people coming here from Typescript, make sure you're importing Request and Response types from "express", otherwise it'll use built-in node.js ones and so the signature will not match. (Sorry for commenting here Fabian, seemed less important than adding an answer.)